# Last record id not fetched properly in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I'm trying to retrieve last record id of my subscriptions table in laravel 6

Following is my function

```
public function activateApp($id)
    {
        $app = App::where('appId','=',$id)->firstOrFail();
        if($app->payment_option == 'monthly')
        {
            $renewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 day"))));
        }
        else
        {
            $renewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+365 day"))));
        }

        $lastdata = DB::table('subscriptions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        //dd($lastdata);
        //die();

        //update app table records
        DB::table('apps')
            ->where('appId', $id)
            ->update([
                'status' => $lastdata,
                'renewDate' => $renewDate
            ]);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

I have used

```
$lastdata = DB::table('subscriptions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

to get the id, but when it  seem to be not working as when i try to update my app table ststus column from that value, it's not updating and not even giving an error..even the 'dd' is not working as well.

(Whole function seem to be stopped working after that last record fetching )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update the `status` with the whole `$lastdata` object.

I do not know your database schema, but probably you should try something like

```
            DB::table('apps')
                ->where('appId', $id)
                ->update([
                    'status' => $lastdata->status,
                    'renewDate' => $renewDate
                ]);
```

You may also double check that the database `subscriptions` has rows and it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to update the status field with the object of the subscriptions. and One more thing is you don't need to retrieve the application object again as you already have so just change the value and save it.

```
public function activateApp($id) {
    $app = App::where('appId','=',$id)->firstOrFail();
    if($app->payment_option == 'monthly')
    {
        $renewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 day"))));
    }
    else
    {
        $renewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+365 day"))));
    }

    $lastdata = DB::table('subscriptions')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

    //update app table records
    $app->status = $lastdata->status;
    $app->renewDate = $renewDate;

    if ($app->save()) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    } else {
        // show some error page.
    }

}
```